# Word for “awful,” in the old sense, for life-and-death power

Tags: single-word-requests

The jury has a ____ power, a ____ responsibility. With the stroke of a pen, it can change lives, even end them. Same for a judge, a military general, the president.

I want “awful” or “awesome” in their older literal sense, but these are too overused down now.

I want to capture the breathtaking importance with which this power is wielded, also some sense of the solemn and sacred responsibility.

A word like “dreadful” or “terrifying” might work, but those contain a sense of fear that I don’t necessarily want.

Comment: A quick look on http://www.thesaurus.com/ (you did check there, right?) suggests "intimidating", "formidable", "awe-inspiring", "daunting" ...

Comment: Sounds like "almighty" would work.

Comment: I'm still happy not to surrender 'awesome' to the trivialisers.

Comment: I'd use **momentous** and **solemn**

Comment: ........awesome

Comment: Please, please, please learn how to use a thesaurus!!!  Simply Googling `awesome synonym` will get you at least 200 excellent suggestions.  Failing to do so will get you many close votes and downvotes.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I even use paper ones! Rodale’s is my go-to. But I’ve struggled with this question for years. It regularly comes up when I teach political theory (Stanford, then Brown, now Columbia). I always string together synonyms, but that ruins the delivery. I thought I’d look for some insights here.

Comment: Garner 3rd says the newer meanings for awful are now too established to fight.

Comment: But "awful" never meant literally life-or-death power.  Rather, it meant "fear inspiring" or some such.  If you want a word that means life-or-death power you need to start somewhere else.  (And regardless, when asking for a word or phrase you must disclose what research you've done.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the aspect of awe that you want to emphasize, there are several words that should do the job.

If you want to emphasize the fear-inducing, intimidating nature of an awful power, "fearsome" seems a good choice.

If you want it to remain a bit more neutral, even encouraging, "fantastic" would work.

If you want to emphasize the reverential type of awe, "marvelous" fits.

Comment: "marvelous" sounds a bit camp, I think.  "Oh it must be simply *marvelous* being on a jury!"

Comment: @Max Williams - I can think of older works on social and civic duty I've read that would address the issue in exactly that tone. "Gaining Favor with God and Man" by Thayer comes to mind immediately.

Comment: Great, but I'm not sure that satisfies the requirement of *"I want to capture the breathtaking importance with which this power is wielded, also some sense of the solemn and sacred responsibility."*

Comment: @Max Williams - That is precisely the reason I offered the other terms. It all depends on how the writer/speaker wants to present that power. It might be fearsome to someone who fears responsibility or who fears that the jury or system is unjust, and it might be fantastic to the more detached to think that we give so much power to the system. To a principled, virtuous person with a high regard for civic duty, they may find the concept of serving on a jury marvelous, as they have the opportunity to play a vital part in a system they believe is one of the most sacred in their society.

Comment: I don’t want to say that you should be scared, in the sense that the prudent thing is to back out of the situation if possible. Indeed, if you are up to it, you should feel a noble and majestic honor. But you should know that your decisions could send people to their deaths, and yes that should scare you.

So I think Jjbroux’s “fearsome” is best so far.